# What naming convention to use for CRUD urls when additional data is needed?

Tags: url, model-view-controller

I'm designing routes for CRUD operations in a hierarchical system. I'm referring to the UI pages for these operations that the browser would GET to display to the user, not the REST API endpoints to read or submit changes.

So, for instance, I have a `state` entity that contains `region` entities.

The natural endpoints for `region` are something like:

```
READ: /regions/{regionId}                 (a page showing the region info in a read only manner)
UPDATE: /regions/{regionId}/edit          (same, but editable, with a button to Save)
DELETE: /regions/{regionId}/delete        (same, but with a Delete button, and probably optional)
```

but I'm stuck on `CREATE`; because this is hierarchical, you can't add a region without knowing the parent `state` data. Which of the following is best?

```
CREATE: /states/{stateId}/regions/add
CREATE: /regions/add/{stateId}
CREATE: /regions/add?stateId={stateId}
CREATE: /regions/add   {some other way to pass the stateId? What could that be?}
```